# How can I use the Python interpreter included in an exe file generated with PyInstaller to run subprocess calls on other machines without Python?

Tags: python, subprocess, pyinstaller, call, launcher

I'm trying to build a Python based program, compiled in an exe with PyInstaller (--onefile), and I want that program to be a laucher of other scripts located in the machine. I tried to run these other scripts with a subprocess call:

```
subprocess.call(['python', 'SCRIPT.py'])
```

And since i use it on my machine it's running just fine! But when i want to use it on another machine, with no Python interpreter installed, the calling method just die here.

Of course i need an interpreter, but i just want to use the one included in the exe file that already run the code of the main script.

I tried not to use the --onefile option, but there is no python.exe file in the 'dist' folder that i can use.

Any idea or other approach that i can use?

I tried the subprocess.call method and i tried to access the inner interpreter by using the PyInstaller tools, but with no luck.

Comment: There is a [closed issue on the pyinstaller github page](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2490) which seems to similar to what you are looking for

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. Just tried the '''exec(open('exyernal_script.py').read())''' approach and, after severals mods to my code it worked! Thanks again!